# javascript onbeforeunload then onunload event

Tags: javascript

Trying to use `onbeforeunload` then `onunload` but the `onunload` script does not seem to work.

```
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit();
  window.onunload = unloading();                  
  function unloading() {
      alert("testicles");
      confirm("try");
  }
  function confirmExit(evt) {
      return 'test1';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you missed "()" while calling unloading function.
Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit();
window.onunload = unloading();
```